# Convert all rasters in a rasterstack to polygons

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2

I need to convert all rasters in a RasterStack to polygons and give the polygons names according to its respective raster.

```R
library(raster)

## r is a single raster
rpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)

## rstack is a raster stack
lapply(rstack, rasterToPolygons)
```

But this lapply function returned the following error.

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply(r,..)` fails because even though a stack has *some* semantics of a list (like defining `r[[1]]` to `r[[N]]`) that's not sufficient for `lapply` to work with a raster stack.

Convert your stack to a list of single-band rasters with `as.list`, then `lapply` as usual:

My stack:

```
> s
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 4, 4, 16, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values  :       1,       1,       1 
max values  :       2,       2,       2
```

`lapply` as a list:

```
> polylist = lapply(as.list(s), rasterToPolygons)
```

Output is a list of polygon layers:

```
> str(polylist, max=2)
List of 3
 $ :Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
 $ :Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
 $ :Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
>
```

No other packages need installing.